# Gerrit - cannot find user by email when using set-reviewers

Tags: ssh, gerrit

I've been trying to add users as reviewers to changes. I've stumbled upon a strange issue. If I identify users by their username, everything goes smoothly. If I identify them by email, Gerrit complains.

what works:

```
ssh -p 29418 user@review.example.com gerrit set-reviewers --add username changeid
```

what doesn't work:

```
ssh -p 29418 user@review.example.com gerrit set-reviewers --add username@example.com changeid
```

The user has *username* as their user name and *username@example.com* as their email address.
What Gerrit responds with is:

```
error: could not add username@example com: username@example.com does not identify a registered user or group
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved it myself, peeking in the source code helped.

The SSH command *set-reviewers* is handled by a class named *PostReviewers*. This delegates to *AccountsCollection* to parse the reviewer and turn it into an account id. This is where the problem is - I have two users identified by the same email address, so *AccountsCollection#_parse(String)* returns nothing.

Why two accounts with the same email? I've got multiple instances of Gerrit I work with, I log in via OpenID, and on one environment I need to see my changes from the "parent" environment. That's where a small hack in the database was applied and everything worked. Until now :)